# jQuery Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: jquery

I am validating a form with the following code:

```
$('#wpcf7-f96-o1 form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = [
        '[name="text-854"]',
        '[name="text-855"]',
        '[name="text-856"]',
        '[name="email-375"]'
    ]
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        if($('input'+value).val() == ''){
            $('input'+value).css({'border':'1px solid red'})
            valid = false
        } else {
            $('input'+value).css({'border':'1px solid #888'})
            valid = true
        }
    })
    if(valid){
        $('#wpcf7-f96-o1 form').submit()
        $('.form_success').css({'display':'block'});
        return false;
    } else {
        $('.form_error').css({'display':'block'});
        return false;
    }
});
```

From reading stack overflow about this issue I understand that it is probably an infinite loop somewhere.. I am just not sure exactly what I am doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: You're triggering a submit within the submit handler, ending up in an infinite loop. Your logic doesn't make sense in that regard either, as you `return false` from the submit handler after raising the same event on the same form, so I'm not sure exactly what behaviour you're expecting.

Comment: @ Stryner not sure what you are trying to do but that wont work. @Rory McCrossan I want the form to submit if valid is true (all fields have values). So I should remove the e.preventDefault() and then return false if the data doesn't exist..?

Comment: That's right. I added an answer with a full example for you.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are triggering a submit event within the submit event handler and ending up in an infinite loop.

> I want the form to submit if valid is true (all fields have values)

If this is the case you should move `e.preventDefault()` from it's current location and only call it when `valid` is not true. Try this:

```
$('#wpcf7-f96-o1 form').submit(function(e) {
    var data = [
        '[name="text-854"]',
        '[name="text-855"]',
        '[name="text-856"]',
        '[name="email-375"]'
    ];

    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        if($('input' + value).val() == ''){
            $('input' + value).css({ 'border': '1px solid red' })
            valid = false
        } else {
            $('input' + value).css({ 'border': '1px solid #888' })
            valid = true
        }
    });

    if (valid) {
        $('.form_success').show();
    } else {
        e.preventDefault(); // stop the form submission here
        $('.form_error').show();
    }
});
```

Also note that it would be better practice to add/remove classes as defined in an external stylesheet than to add custom rules via the `css()` method.

Comment: Only problem with this is that the form no longer send the email on successful validation

Comment: I assume the email is sent from the server when the form is submit? I would look at debugging the server code which handles the form data.